# Vantage points in Buenos Aires for photos

Tags: photography, vantage-points, buenos-aires

Are there any publicly accessible tall buildings in Buenos Aires that are good for views & photos? And hopefully pleasant to visit otherwise too. :)

Including (or linking to) opening hours & prices would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The [two most promising](https://vamospanish.com/5-places-to-get-the-best-views-of-buenos-aires/) would be:

- [Galería Güemes](http://galeriaguemes.com.ar/mirador)'s observation deck, open Monday to Friday from 15 to 17.40 and Thursday until 7 pm.  [Image gallery](http://galeriaguemes.com.ar/mirador).
- [Palacio Barolo](https://palaciobarolo.com.ar/?lang=en), where [the guided tours](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/argentina/buenos-aires/attractions/palacio-barolo/a/poi-sig/394571/363005) between 10am-7pm Wed-Sun visit the rooftop lighthouse.  [Image gallery](https://palaciobarolotours.com.ar/en/galeria/)